# De-Serializing Json with Newtonsoft Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, serialization, json.net, azure-webjobs

I writing a console application that uses a Web API (web api 2) to get data.   The console application passes a complex object into the web api (no problem so far).  I am using Newtonsoft json to serialize/deserialize data.  The issue is that when I deserialize the return data in the console application, it comes back unusable.  Below is the data returned-

> [\"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\"]

The data being returned should be an arraylist of byte arrays after it is deserialized.  However the below error is generated instead upon trying to deserialize-

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in
>   Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>
> Additional information: Error converting value
>   "["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"]"
>   to type 'System.Collections.ArrayList'. Path '', line 1, position
>   1524.

Below is the code-
WEB API-

```
public class BatchController : ApiController
{
    [ActionName("DoBatchWork")]
    [HttpPost]
    public string DoBatchWork([FromBody]JObject jWork)
    {
        JObject s = JObject.Parse(jWork.ToString());

        BatchPrintBatchInfo objWork = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BatchPrintBatchInfo>(s.ToString());
        ArrayList aryWork = DocumentByBatchReports.CreateBatchReport(objWork);
        string a = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(aryWork);
        return a;

    }

}
```

WEB JOB-

```
    public static ArrayList DoBatchWork(BatchPrintBatchInfo Work)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        var content = new StringContent(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Work), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        string result = SendRequest("Batch/DoBatchWork", content, HttpMethod.Post);

        //******FAILS HERE*************
        ArrayList deserialized = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ArrayList>(result);


        return deserialized;
    }

    public static string SendRequest(string requestUrl, StringContent content, HttpMethod httpMethod)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(serviceUrl) };
        var uri = new Uri(serviceUrl + requestUrl); // http://localhost/api/test

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpResponseMessage response;
        response = client.PostAsync(uri, content).Result;

        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(response.ToString());
        }

        string stringResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        return stringResult;
    }
```

EDIT
BATCHPRINTBATCHINFO CODE-

```
         using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace RENO_BatchPrintGenerator.PropertyClasses
{
    #region "BatchPrintBatchInfo"
    [Serializable()]
    public class BatchPrintBatchInfo
    {

        // local property declarations
        int _id;
        int _renoBatchPrintCategoryID;
        Nullable<DateTime> _createdDate;
        Nullable<DateTime> _deletedDate;
        string _batchType;
        int _printCount;
        DateTime _requestDate;
        Nullable<DateTime> _lastPrintDate;
        Nullable<DateTime> _lastLabelsPrintDate;
        int _userId;
        string _userFullname;
        string _filename;
        string _filenameLabels;

        bool _notifyUser;
        #region "Constructors"
        public BatchPrintBatchInfo()
        {
        }

        public BatchPrintBatchInfo(int renoBatchPrintCategoryID, DateTime createdDate, string batchType, int printCount, DateTime requestDate, int userId, DateTime deletedDate)
        {
            this.ID = 0;
            this.RenoBatchPrintCategoryID = renoBatchPrintCategoryID;
            this.CreatedDate = createdDate;
            this.DeletedDate = deletedDate;
            this.BatchType = batchType;
            this.PrintCount = printCount;
            this.RequestDate = requestDate;
            this.LastPrintDate = null;
            this.LastLabelsPrintDate = null;
            this.UserID = userId;
            this.UserFullname = "";
            this.Filename = "";
            this.FilenameLabels = "";
            this.NotifyUser = false;
        }
        #endregion

        #region "Public Properties"
        public int ID
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { _id = value; }
        }

        public int RenoBatchPrintCategoryID
        {
            get { return _renoBatchPrintCategoryID; }
            set { _renoBatchPrintCategoryID = value; }
        }

        public Nullable<DateTime> CreatedDate
        {
            get { return _createdDate; }
            set { _createdDate = value; }
        }

        public Nullable<DateTime> DeletedDate
        {
            get { return _deletedDate; }
            set { _deletedDate = value; }
        }

        public string BatchType
        {
            get { return _batchType; }
            set { _batchType = value; }
        }

        public int PrintCount
        {
            get { return _printCount; }
            set { _printCount = value; }
        }

        public DateTime RequestDate
        {
            get { return _requestDate; }
            set { _requestDate = value; }
        }

        public Nullable <DateTime> LastPrintDate
        {
            get { return _lastPrintDate; }
            set { _lastPrintDate = value; }
        }

        public Nullable<DateTime> LastLabelsPrintDate
        {
            get { return _lastLabelsPrintDate; }
            set { _lastLabelsPrintDate = value; }
        }

        public string UserFullname
        {
            get { return _userFullname; }
            set { _userFullname = value; }
        }

        public int UserID
        {
            get { return _userId; }
            set { _userId = value; }
        }

        public string Filename
        {
            get { return _filename; }
            set { _filename = value; }
        }

        public string FilenameLabels
        {
            get { return _filenameLabels; }
            set { _filenameLabels = value; }
        }

        public bool NotifyUser
        {
            get { return _notifyUser; }
            set { _notifyUser = value; }
        }
        #endregion
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Add the code for the class `BatchPrintBatchInfo`

Comment: @Gusman - BatchPrintBatchInfo added.

Comment: Ok, are you sure it's an ArrayList of byte arrays and not an ArrayList of bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is an array of bytes, any `IEnumerable<byte>` will be serialized as Base64. but as `ArrayList` is not `IEnumerable<byte>` but `IEnumerable` then the deserializer does not know what to do with the Base64 data as the `ArrayList` content is not defined (it's `object`). If you deserialize it to a `byte[]` or to a `List<byte>` it will work.

Per example:

```
byte[] deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<byte[]>(result);
```

Also, avoid as much as you can `ArrayList`, use real arrays or generic collections like `List<T>`

EDIT: You really have an ArrayList with one byte[] inside, my fault, then the correct deserialization code should be:

```
List<byte[]> deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<byte[]>>(result);
```

This is the full test working with your data:

```
string data = "[\"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\"]";

List<byte[]> datdes = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<byte[]>>(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you see is a base64 encoded format, if you try to decode it you see a PDF file.

Most probably the `BatchPrintBatchInfo Work` parameters contains the print output as PDF

Comment: i did try Base64Decode method and removed json characters prior to decoding.  i did get text that in part was readable, and seemed to indicated PDF as you say.  However, Would like to get this working with a method returning an array list of byte arrays.

Comment: list of byte arrays of what ?

Comment: SSRS reports turned into byte arrays to be written out to a NAS drive in the form of PDF's.

Comment: Why you don't convert from base64 and save the content to the file ? You have already have the PDF. Why you want to convert to bytes ?